# Testing a before_save callback with Rspec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

I am pretty sure I am missing something really basic here.

I want to test if a `before_save` callback does what it is supposed to do, not just that it is called.

I wrote the following test:

```
it 'should add lecture to question_type' do      
  @course = Factory :course,
                    :start_time => Time.now - 1.hour,
                    :end_time => Time.now                        
  @question = Factory.create(:question, 
                             :course_id => @course.id, 
                             :created_at => Time.now - 10.minutes)                          
  @question.question_type.should == 'lecture'      
end
```

And I have the following factories for `course` and `question`:

```
Factory.define :course do |c|
  c.dept_code {"HIST"}
  c.course_code { Factory.next(:course_code) }
  c.start_time { Time.now - 1.hour }
  c.end_time { Time.now }
  c.lecture_days { ["Monday", Time.now.strftime('%A'), "Friday"]  }
end

Factory.define :question do |q|
  q.content {"Why don't I understand this class!?"}
  q.association :course
end
```

And I wrote the following callback in my `Question` model:

```
before_save :add_type_to_question

protected

def add_type_to_question
  @course = Course.find(self.course_id)
  now     = Time.now
  if (time_now > lecture_start_time && time_now < lecture_end_time ) && @course.lecture_days.map{|d| d.to_i}.include?(Time.now.wday)
    self.question_type = "lecture"
  end    
end
```

The test keeps failing saying that "got: nil" for question_type instead of 'lecture'

Since I didn't see anything obviously wrong with my implementation code, I tried the callback in my development environment and it actually worked adding 'lecture' to question_type.

This makes me think that there might be something wrong with my test. What am I missing here? Does `Factory.create` skip callbacks by default?

Comment: Instead of before_save try before_validation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not use `Factory.create` to trigger the process. FactoryGirl should be used to create the test setup, not to trigger the actual code you want to test. Your test would then look like:

```
it 'should add lecture to question_type' do      
  course = Factory(:course, :start_time => Time.now - 1.hour, :end_time => Time.now)
  question = Factory.build(:question, :course_id => course.id, :created_at => Time.now - 10.minutes, :question_type => nil)

  question.save!                          
  question.reload.question_type.should == 'lecture'      
end
```

If this test still fails, you can start debugging:

Add a puts statement inside `add_type_to_question` and another one inside the `if` statement and see what happens.